# Spotify track is not playing after I stopped `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer` track

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, mpmusicplayercontroller, cocoalibspotify-2.0

In my application, I am using `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer` for the playing song of Apple music, it's working fine. But when I play back Spotify track using `playSpotifyURI` it's not working. I have checked logs but not showing error anywhere.

**Scenario**

Step 1. Play track using `playSpotifyURI`. It is playing fine

```
SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().playSpotifyURI(itemID, startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 0) { error in
            if error != nil {
                print("*** failed to play: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }else{
                print("Playing!!")
            }
        }
```

Step 2. stop track using.

```
SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().setIsPlaying(false, callback: { (error) in

                            })
```

Step 3. play apple music song using the`MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer`

```
func beginPlayback(itemID: String) {
        if musicPlayerController.playbackState == .playing {
            musicPlayerController.stop()
        }
        //musicPlayerController.setQueue(with: [itemID]) //1324456545
        musicPlayerController.setQueue(with: [itemID])
        musicPlayerController.prepareToPlay { (error) in
            print("prepareToPlay----------------")
        }
        musicPlayerController.play()
    }
```

Step 4. Stop Apple music song using.

```
if musicPlayerController.playbackState == .playing {
            musicPlayerController.stop()
        }
```

Step 5. Play track using `playSpotifyURI` using below code but it's not playing, I couldn't find any error.

```
SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().playSpotifyURI(itemID, startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 0) { error in
            if error != nil {
                print("*** failed to play: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }else{
                print("Playing!!")
            }
        }
```

Is there any issue in the above code? Please help me to solve an issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. did you find any solution for the above issue?

Comment: Nope, I don't find any solution.

Comment: So did you get any workaround for the same?